# get variable in tkinter frame class and send it to another python script

Tags: python, class, tkinter

i need to send one variable from one tkinter script to other python script.
my code is like this.

```
import os  
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

        ## class parent and parameter

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageDigital(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)      

        entry = Entry(self,  width=13, font=("Helvetica", 20))
        entry.place(x=50, y=300)

        def OK():
            os.system('pri.py')
        button21 = tk.Button(self, text="OK", font=("Helvetica", 15), width=8,command=OK)
        button21.place(x=300, y=300)

write1=entry1["text"]
import pri
app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

i need to send string inside entry to pri.py and print it
pri.py script is like this

```
from __main__ import *
print write1
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try making the OK function pass `entry.get()` to the pri.py script, this should pass the value of the StringVar to your script.

If you need to close your frame before passing/printing it, turn the entry into a member variable (`self.entry = Entry(..)`) and access it outside of the class/functions with `app.entry.get()`.

**EDIT 06/27**: New code example. Here you can see how I'm able to use the class structure to access the variable obtained from the first `Entry` field and display it in the `Label` of the `Toplevel`. I hope this is able to help as I'm not 100% sure on what you're trying to do.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window():

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.f = Frame(root)
        self.f.pack()

        self.e = Entry(self.f, width = 20)
        self.e.pack(side = LEFT)

        self.b = Button(self.f, width = 15, text = "OK", command = lambda: self.OK(root))
        self.b.pack(side = RIGHT)

    def OK(self, root):

        print ("Accessing entry inside class: %s" %self.e.get()) #Could pass to pri.py here
        self.word = self.e.get() 
        new = self.newWindow()
        root.wait_window(new)
        root.destroy()

    def newWindow(self):

        def done(newWindow):

            newWindow.destroy()

        newWindow = Toplevel()
        newWindow.tkraise()  # <- Personally never needed this, but it's in

        l = Label(newWindow, text = "Here is the variable in a top window: %s" %self.word)  #Using the variable in another window
        l.pack(side = LEFT)

        b = Button(newWindow, text = "Done", command = lambda: done(newWindow))
        b.pack(side = RIGHT)

        return newWindow

root = Tk()
w = Window(root)
w.f.mainloop()
print ("Accessing entry outside class: %s" %w.word)  #Or here
```

Comment: What should i do if i want to raise new frame and bring the previous frame variable? Sorry for my stupidity, but i can't do the get method and the raise method at the same time

Comment: @Daniel Budiono  Check out my latest code edit; I'm not 100% certain on what you're trying to do but I hope it's able to help you. Basically I added in how I'm able to raise a new `Toplevel` window and display my variable within that as well